# Hibernate multiple @OneToOne relations to the same class objects

Tags: java, hibernate, relationship

I have an entity with 2 relations to the same `Parcel` class, but different objects:

```
@Entity
public class Parcel implements Serializable
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne( mappedBy = "parcelSender", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Place sender;

    @OneToOne( mappedBy = "parcelRecipient", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER )
    private Place recipient;

//getters, setters, etc.
}
```

`Place` entity:

```
@Entity
public class Place implements Serializable
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    private Parcel parcelSender;

    @OneToOne
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    private Parcel parcelRecipient;

//getters, setters
}
```

If you see, I have 2 `@OneToOne` relations to the `Place` objects. Everything works almost good - when I persist objects with REST, I get JSON response where sender and recipient are correct. When I want patch `Parcels` object then I get JSON Response where sender and recipient point to the same data. 
For example, I persist object:

```
{
    "sender":{
        "name": "John",
        "email":"othermail@mail.com"
    },
    "recipient":{
        "name": "Mike",
        "email":"mymail@mail.com",       
    }
}
```

and I get response with persisted data:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "sender": {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "John",
    "email": "othermail@mail.com"
  },
  "recipient": {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Mike",
    "email": "mymail@mail.com"
  }
}
```

Now, when I want to patch some fields in Parcel entity, I have same objects in JSON reposne:

I patch with (this is above parcel id):

```
{
    "id": 1   
    //some not important data
}
```

And response:

```
{
  "id": 3,
  "sender": {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Mike",
    "email": "mymail@mail.com"
  },
  "recipient": {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Mike",
    "email": "mymail@mail.com"
  }
}
```

Probably the problem is easy, but I do not know how to solve it. I really don't understand why I get same objects even when they have different `mappedBy` in entities. I need to have two `@OneToOne` relations to same classes but different objects. Is it possible to solve this problem in clever way?

Comment: Did you get a solution??